# Jersey filter starting exception while using forEach

Tags: jersey, jersey-client, jersey-1.0

**Method definition:**

```
@POST
@Path("/run")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public String runSomething(CustomInputModel customInputModel) {
    // With simple loop
    for (String machine : customInputModel.getListOfString()) {
       .....
    }

    // With forEach
    customInputModel.getListOfString().forEach((stringObj) -> {
       .....    
    });

}
```

**CustomInputModel class Definition:**

```
public class CustomInputModel(){

private List<String> listOfString; 

public List<String> getListOfString() {
    return listOfString;
}

public void setListOfString(List<String> listOfString) {
    this.listOfString = listOfString;
}

}
```

**Problem:**

In the runSomething method -> If the simple loop is used, everything works fine. However if I use forEach then I get the error below. Any help is appreciated. Apologies if I have missed something obvious.

**Error:**

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter jersey
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 25460
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readClass(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener.onProcess(AnnotationScannerListener.java:133)
at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.uri.FileSchemeScanner$1.f(FileSchemeScanner.java:86)
```